# MSI Installer: Conditionally detect ARM platform

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Essentially the same question as [MSI Installer: Conditionally include one or another file for 32 or 64-bit systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268661/msi-installer-conditionally-include-one-or-another-file-for-32-or-64-bit-system) but I want to detect Windows on ARM instead of x86/x64, so I can choose one of three different files based on platform information

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what tool you are using to build your MSI.

Last time I checked there was no native support in Windows Installer to get this information so for packages built with Advanced Installer we added a custom code to [detect the platform](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-OS-dependent-install.html) and set the property **AiArm64** accordingly.

Other installer authoring tools might not provide this support at all, or they might use a different detection logic.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: As tagged in the question, we are using wix

Comment: Missed that, sorry. Last time I checked Wix relied only on the native VersionNT property to help you detect the OS version where the package is installed. I am not aware of any new updates to Wix that would help you detect ARM architectures.

The only option you have is to create a DTF custom action to detect the platform and from that custom action set a property of your choice accordingly. Then you can use that property to condition the file installation.

Answer (score 0):

WiX's [QueryNativeMachine](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/util/querynativemachine/) element lets you query the underlying machine architecture.